# Friend function doesn't have acces to private members

Tags: c++

so I declared on 2 friend functions so they'll have acces to 2 other class like this:

```
    friend int Birthday(Student** student, Worker** worker, int sizeS, int sizeW, MyDate date);
    friend bool Check(Student** student, Worker** worker, int sizeS, int sizeW, char* ID);
```

Its in each header file, in public.

Now, when Im writing the function in main.cpp, while writing the function 'Check', I have acces to each class (worker and student) private variables, but when I write 'Birthday' function, also in main.cpp, I only have acces to worker private, and not to student. Why is that? What do I need to do?

Worker.H

```
#ifndef  Worker
#include "MyDate.h"
class Student;
class Worker {
private:
    char* name;
    char ID[9];
    MyDate birthdate;
    float wage;
    int workH, extraH;
public:
    Worker(char*, char*, MyDate, int);
    Worker(const Worker&);
    ~Worker();
    void Print();
    float Salary();
    void Set(int, int);
    friend int Birthday(Student** student, Worker** worker, int sizeS, int sizeW, MyDate date);
    friend bool Check(Student** student, Worker** worker, int sizeS, int sizeW, char* ID);
};
#endif // ! Worker
```

Student.H

```
#ifndef Student
#include "MyDate.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Worker;
class Student {
private:
    char* name;
    char ID[9];
    MyDate birthdate;
    int courses;
    int* list;
public:
    Student(char*, char*, int, int, int);
    Student(const Student&);
    ~Student();
    void Print();
    float Average();
    bool CheckS(int);
    friend int Birthday(Student** student, Worker** worker, int sizeS, int sizeW, MyDate date);
    friend bool Check(Student** student, Worker** worker, int sizeS, int sizeW, char* ID);
};
#endif
```

Part of the main.cpp(unfinished)

```
#include "MyDate.h"
#include "Student.h"
#include "Worker.h"
#include <iostream>
class MyDate;
class Student;
class Worker;

MyDate* MyDate::min = NULL;
MyDate* MyDate::max = NULL;

bool Check(Student** student, Worker** worker, int sizeS, int sizeW, char* ID) { //this function has acces to all the private members of both classes
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeS; i++) {
        if (!(strcmp(student[i]->ID, ID)))
            return false;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < sizeW; i++) {
        if (!(strcmp(worker[i]->ID, ID)))
            return false;
    }
    return true; 
}

int Birthday(Student** student, Worker** worker, int sizeS, int sizeW, MyDate date) { //this function doesnt have acces to student's private
    int counter = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeS; i++) {
        if ((student[i]->birthdate.Get_Year == date.Get_Year) && (student[i]->birthdate.Get_Month == date.Get_Month)
            && ) student[i]->name;
    } 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hopefully before you get too deep into this code base you can switch over to [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and avoid ugly C-style arrays. Passing in two `const std::vector<Student*>&` is a lot less messy than pointer-to-array + length combination arguments, especially with the strange inter-leaving you have here. Most of the power in C++ comes from the Standard Library, especially with its various iterators. Use it whenever you can!

Comment: Yes man I know, but unfortunately thats how my lecturer wants us to write for now, I believe that its because we just learned C, but thanks!

Comment: I swear educators like that are often the biggest obstacle to learning. Hope you can survive that course without picking up too many bad habits. One thing to remember here is that it's often helpful to create a minimal example, especially for C++, that demonstrates the exact nature of your problem. This is still a lot of guess-work as to how that meshes with the rest of your code.

Comment: gunna need more than just the friend declarations to diagnose your problem with any certainty. please supply the minimum code that exhibits your issue. as a simple check, double check that your friend declaration and the function definition match

Comment: Alright hehe, added  @tadman , I totaly agree, it messes things up to much.

Comment: Define "I only have acces to worker private, and not to student". If you're getting a compilation error, show the compilation error. The error message you get is not produced by a random number generator. The compiler will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: On a side note, your include guards are incomplete: you have `#ifndef  Worker`, but then you should `#define Worker`, otherwise `ifndef` will always be true and that block will be added every time the file is included, leading to errors due to multiple definitions of the same class. You can read more on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Comment: @FabioTurati well I haven't got to compiling the code, because while writing the code, it shows me red underline under "birthdate" and says that it is inaccesible. Also, in "brithday" function, when I type "student[i]->" it doesnt show me the private members, just the public functions, while in "Check" function, it does. And thank you on that note.

Comment: @FabioTurati Of course, the `#defined` macro should be something other than the class name.

Comment: I don't trust IDE underlines.  Do you get error messages if you try to compiler despite the underlines?

Comment: @MatanBenishty c++ is different then managed code languages like c# and sometimes can not be properly validate by IDE. Partial compilation also can produce weird errors. If you see something impossible try to use recompile option (or even clean whole project and compile again).

Comment: Btw. it is not magic probably intellisense was rebuild after project reopen.

Comment: @aschepler You are right, I had completely overlooked that. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

More likely it's just your implementation of ur second method is not compiling due to undone if statement.

See below everything works fine...
**Student.h**

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H

class Worker;

class Student {
    int pks=0;
public:
    Student(){};
    ~Student(){};

    friend int Birthday(Student s, Worker w);
    friend bool Check(Student s, Worker w);
};
#endif
```

**Worker.h**

```
#ifndef WORKER_H
#define WORKER_H

class Student;

class Worker {
    int pkw=1;
public:
    Worker(){};
    ~Worker(){};

    friend int Birthday(Student s, Worker w);
    friend bool Check(Student s, Worker w);
};
#endif
```

And eventually **main.cc**

```
#include "Student.h"
#include "Worker.h"

int Birthday(Student s, Worker w)
{return s.pks;}

bool Check(Student s, Worker w)
{return w.pkw==1;}
```

tested with the command:

```
g++ main.cc -c
```

Comment: Its before compiling, it just doesnt give me acces to the private member of "Students", in "brithday" function, when I type "student[i]->" it doesnt show me the private members, just the public functions, while in "Check" function, it does.

Comment: when you say, "*it doesnt show me*", can you be more precise? **What** doesn't show you the members? Are you using an IDE or smart editor of some kind? If so, what is it?

Comment: @Robᵩ Im using Visual Studio. And what I mean when Im saying "it doesnt show me" is that the menue that opens, let me chose only the public functions, and not the private members. When I manually type it, it show me that red underline and the error that "birthdate (for example) is inaccesible"